# How can I pass a structure's array in the right way to my function?

Tags: c, function, pointers, struct

I am trying to pass a structure's array to a function, but it gives me an error when `i` becomes 1, `acces violation`.
Here is my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <conio.h>

typedef struct {
  int locuri;
  int putere;
  char marca[50];
  char culoare[50];
  int an_fabricatie;
}automob;

void aloca(automob **autos, int n)
{
   *autos = (automob*)malloc(sizeof(automob)*n);
   if (autos == NULL) {
      exit(1);
   }
}

void read_autos(const char* filename, automob **A, int *n)
{
    FILE *f_in = fopen(filename, "r");
    int i = 0, aux;
    if (f_in == NULL) {
        printf("Nu s-a gasit fisierul!");
        _getch();
        exit(0);
    }
    fscanf(f_in, "%d", n);
    aloca(A, *n);
    while (i < (*n)) {
        fscanf(f_in, "%d", &A[i]->locuri);
        fscanf(f_in, "%d", &A[i]->putere);
        fscanf(f_in, "%s", &A[i]->marca);
        fscanf(f_in, "%s", &A[i]->culoare);
        fscanf(f_in, "%d", &A[i]->an_fabricatie);
        i++;
    }
}

void main()
{
    int n;
    automob *A;
    read_autos("autos.in", &A, &n);
    _getch();
}
```

I think the pointer A is not allocated properly but I really don't know. Do you have any ideas? Because this works when I write it in the main function but does not work if I right it in another function like `read_autos`.

Comment: you better check the n value after the fscanf(f_in,"%d",n); because i m kinda sure the problem is there

Comment: Use brackets after the `&` in your fscanf statements. Example : `&A[i]->locuri` should be `&(A[i]->locuri)`

Comment: I checked the n and  it is ok, it gets the right value. And i also put brackets buts still doesnt work. Acces violating writing location 0xCCCCCCCC

Comment: It literally works for A[0] but when it goes at A[1] it gives me the error

Comment: On a side note, do not use `void main()` please.

Comment: Offtopic: `aloca` is unluckily chosen - there's a (non-standard!) [`alloca`](https://linux.die.net/man/3/alloca) function in some environments (linux/GNU, BSD, even MSVC seems to know about)...

Comment: You do not check the results of fscanf! It returns the number of successfully read items (can only be 0 or 1 in your case), but if you get 0, some error occured!

Comment: Just a recommendation: Prefer English identifiers only. If you take it serious, you'll at some day encounter people not capable of Romanian language - and you make life easier for both them (chances are that they understand English...) *and* you (because you are used to already). If not - well, not intermixing different languages at least is more aesthetic...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`A[i] -> locuri` means `(* A[i]).locuri`; this would make sense if `A` was an array of pointers to `automob`; but it isn't. You want `(* A)[i].locuri`. And so on for the other fields.

```
    fscanf(f_in, "%d", &(* A)[i].locuri);
    fscanf(f_in, "%d", &(* A)[i].putere);
    fscanf(f_in, "%s", (* A)[i].marca);
    fscanf(f_in, "%s", (* A)[i].culoare);
    fscanf(f_in, "%d", &(* A)[i].an_fabricatie);
```

What you wrote:

```
+------+     +-------+     +--------------------------------------------+
|  A  -----> | A[0] -----> | locuri | putere | marca | culoare | an_fab |
+------+     |       |     +--------------------------------------------+
             +-------+     +--------------------------------------------+
             | A[1] -----> | locuri | putere | marca | culoare | an_fab |
             |       |     +--------------------------------------------+
             +-------+     +--------------------------------------------+
             | A[2] -----> | locuri | putere | marca | culoare | an_fab |
             |       |     +--------------------------------------------+
             +-------+     +--------------------------------------------+
             | A[3] -----> | locuri | putere | marca | culoare | an_fab |
             |       |     +--------------------------------------------+
             +-------+
```

What you want:

```
+------+     +-------+         +--------------------------------------------+
|  A  -----> | * A  -----> [0] | locuri | putere | marca | culoare | an_fab |
+------+     +-------+         +--------------------------------------------+
                           [1] | locuri | putere | marca | culoare | an_fab |
                               +--------------------------------------------+
                           [2] | locuri | putere | marca | culoare | an_fab |
                               +--------------------------------------------+
                           [3] | locuri | putere | marca | culoare | an_fab |
                               +--------------------------------------------+
```

Comment: Ok and now i got stack around A corrupted and stack around n corrupted

Comment: When using, *pointers-to-pointers-to-ad nauseum*, it is very easy to get confused and have an off-by-one error with regards to the dereferencing-depth. Novices like me, often end up, either dereferencing one level too early or one level too deep. Here was a case of one level too early. Not `A` had `n` elements, but `*A`!

Comment: Ok so now i can write in the structure members i got stack around variable A corrupted

Comment: void aloca(automob **autos, int n)
{
 *autos = (automob*)malloc(sizeof(automob));
 for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
  autos[i] = (automob*)malloc(sizeof(automob));
 }
}

Comment: Tried to allocate something like this

Comment: @RazvanMarian: New problem, new question.

Comment: @RazvanMarian The `aloca` function seemed to be fine as was (well, I'd rather give it a return value, but that's another matter) at a first glance. As a beginner, might be easier for you having (*after* call to `aloca`!) `automob* a = *A; fscanf(/*...*/, &a[i].xyz);` (signature of `read_autos` unchanged).

Comment: @Aconcagua So how do you explain the stack corruption around A then

Comment: Oh, indeed overlooked an error in `aloca`: `if (autos == NULL)` must be `if (*autos == NULL)`

Answer (score 1):

(It is a comment but I do not have 50 reputation, so I answer and you could convert it as a comment)

When I have such problem and it happens, I do not hesitate to simply print pointer value.
For example, in your case :

```
printf("sizeof %I64u\n",sizeof(automob));
printf("Global Addr %I64u\n",*A);
printf("1st elt Addr %I64u\n",&(*A)[0]);
printf("2nd elt Addr %I64u\n",&(*A)[1]);
printf("1st elt / 1st field Addr %I64u\n",&(*A)[0].locuri);
printf("2nd elt / 2nd field Addr %I64u\n",&(*A)[1].locuri);
```